# IOS 8 no longer supports UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a foreign language dictionary type application that allows the use to enter transliterated (to English) words.  The great majority of entries are lowercase, but there are a few entries that are uppercase.  As of IOS 8, searchbar no longer recognizes `UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone`.  This causes considerable frustration for the end-users.  Is there any practical strategy to turn off initial capitalization?  Currently it is off in the storyboard setting for `UISearchBar`

This is an existing application, originally written for iOS 6.  The current Apple documentation states that AutocapitalizationType is available from iOS 2 through iOS 7.1.  Users reported the change after moving to iOS 8.

Comment: When you say it isn't recognized, what do you mean? A compiler warning or is the entered text being capitalized in some way? Show how you setup the search bar.

Comment: @rmaddy The searchbar is setup in a storyboard.  The caps lock key is automatically turned on for the first character, even when using the delete key to move back to the first position.

Comment: `autocapitalizationType` was not deprecated actually. The docs are misleading. Prior to iOS 8.0, `UISearchBar` had the `autocapitalizationType` property. As of iOS 8, the property was removed but the `UITextInputAttributes` protocol was added. This protocol provides the `autocapitalizationType` property. So effectively nothing changed. The property still exists, it's just declared differently. If it's not working through the storyboard, try adding code to set the property directly.

Comment: @rmaddy That solves the problem.  It seems that I need to set it in code:  self.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;  If you put your comment in as an answer, I will mark it.  Thanks...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`autocapitalizationType` was not deprecated actually. The docs are misleading. Prior to iOS 8.0, `UISearchBar` had the `autocapitalizationType` property. As of iOS 8, the property was removed but the `UITextInputAttributes` protocol was added. This protocol provides the `autocapitalizationType` property. So effectively nothing changed. The property still exists, it's just declared differently.

If the storyboard doesn't provide a working way to set the `autocapitalizationType` property, set it in code:

```
self.someSearchbar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

Comment: in Swift use UITextAutocapitalizationType.None

Comment: setting this property in storyboard does nothing, but writing it in code does the trick! So I upvote this answer, thanks!

Comment: In swift, `autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.none` worked for me as of today.